# Access dockerfile ENV variables in entrypoint

Tags: java, shell, docker, dockerfile, docker-entrypoint

I have a dockerfile that declares some environment variables that are being used later in the entrypoint, but the entrypoint never picks up the values for those variables. I tried the shell form but looks like its not doing anything. Here is my sample dockerfile :-

```html
FROM java:8
ENV JAVA_OPTS="
RUN apt-get -y install ca-certificates curl
RUN mkdir /app
RUN mkdir /docker
CMD ["java", "-version"]
ADD /target/app.jar /app/app.jar
ENV spring.profiles.active dev
ENV encryptor.password xyz
COPY entrypoint.sh /docker/entrypoint.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/docker/entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/docker/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ""
```

My entrypoint.sh is very simple and uses these ENV variables :-

```html
#!/bin/bash
java -Djava.security.egd="file:/dev/./urandom" -Dencryptor.password=$encryptor.password -Dspring.profiles.active=$spring.profiles.active -jar /app/app.jar
```

How should i make my ENTRYPOINT to be able to access those ENV variables declared earlier in the Dockerfile so that its able to assign appropriate values to the arguments passed in. Went through several posts and stuffs on the internet and tried lot of ways to get this work, but didn't seem to work a single time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an issue is the periods (dots) within the environment variable names. I think, valid identifiers may only include alphanumeric characters and underscores.

You will also need to use the shell form of `ENTRYPOINT` to get a shell that can do environment variable substitution:

```
FROM busybox

ENV spring_profiles_active dev
ENV encryptor_password xyz

ENTRYPOINT echo ${spring_profiles_active} ${encryptor_password}
```

Then:

```sh
docker build --tag=example --file=./Dockerfile .
docker run --interactive --tty example
```

Returns:

```
dev xyz
```

Comment: I guess you need to tell OP `dot` is not a valid character in a shell identifier.

Comment: That's the first line of my answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I'm not a native English speaker. I don't know `periods` sames with `dot`...

Comment: Thanks everyone. That did the trick. Not sure why shell has issues with dots.Will make sure the java coding for variables do not use dots.